# Swapping Drayton LP722 for smart switch - the wiring

Tags: electrical

I'm replacing my Drayton LP722 control unit which controls the Hot Water only (heating is UFH and controlled via the zone thermostats) with a Smart switch and I am trying to figure out the wiring.

The Drayton unit is wired in for N, L, 3, 4.
The Smart switch I have, has connectors for: N, L1, L2, C.

I think it should be N -> N, L -> L1, 3 -> C.

The bit that is confusing me in the wiring into 4 on the Drayton unit, according to the documentation that is for central heating, but that's not controlled through this unit...

Not sure where this should be wired into.

Smart switch wiring can be found here: https://shop.meross.com/products/meross-two-way-smart-light-switch-eu-uk

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I chased #4 wire back, turns out it's not connected to anything. It's terminated in #12 in the following picture

[image]